# $\log(y)=a+b\log(1+f(x)) $. Is $\frac{d\log(y)}{d\log(x)}= \frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}=\frac{b}{1+f\left(x\right)}\times f'(x)$?

Tags: logarithms

Imagine that we have the following logarithmic function:
$$
\log\left(y\right)=a+b\log\left(1+f\left(x\right)\right)
$$
I wish to compute $\frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}.$
Would this be:
$$
\frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}=\frac{b}{1+f\left(x\right)}\times f'(x)
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Well if $\log y = a + b\log(1 + f(x))$ and you set $u = \log x$ and $v = \log y$
you could write this as $v = a + b\log(1 + f(e^u))$, so
\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{du} = b\frac{f'(e^u)e^u}{1 + f(e^u)}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:
$$\dfrac{d\log(y)}{dx}=\frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}\dfrac{d\log(x)}{dx}=\frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}\dfrac{1}{x}$$

$$\frac{d\log\left(y\right)}{d\log\left(x\right)}=x\dfrac{d\log(y)}{dx}=x\frac{bf'(x)}{1+f\left(x\right)}$$